# Does camera calibration and remap produces a pinhole camera model?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, calibration

I'm using opencv to measure some objects. After doing camera calibration and remapping the original image, can I consider the resulting image as produced by a pinhole camera model? (so I can use the simple equations for x = Xf/Z )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after canceling the lens distortion, the camera model is estimated by a pinhole camera model. But you don't mention what x,X,Z, and f are. Because the equation you have written is really wrong. So if you have a question about that or the coordinate systems feel free to clarify/expand your question.

Comment: I don't think that equation is necessarily wrong. Given `(x,y)` as the image coordinate, `(X,Y,Z)` as the 3D coordinate and `f` as the focal length, wouldn't `x = (fX)/Z`  be correct using the pinhole camera model?

Comment: (X,Y,Z) should be the 3D coordinate of the point in the camera's coordinate system. It's unclear if EduardoFV knows this. And then also you're puting the center of the image space at (0,0) by `x = (fX)/Z`.

Comment: True, but he specified he'd remapped the coordinates, which I took to mean he'd centred the image at (0,0) anyway.

Comment: By remapping, most likely, he means using the remap() function of opencv to cancel the barrel distortion.

Comment: Ahh ok. I don't use OpenCV much anymore for this sort of stuff, so I misunderstood.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Shambool. You are right, I was reffering to the X component of the image. I was aware of the (X,Y,Z) coordinate. Your answer was helpful.